# Solução para comando na Unity 3D

Tags: c#

Preciso de um script C# que faz 2 comandos apertando uma só tecla EX: (quero fazer meu personagem agachar apertando "c" e quando apertar de novo o personagem subir novamente) alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente tu precisa de um sinalizador par marcar se ele está agachado ou não.

```
private boolean agachado = false;

    public void keyPressEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
       if(e.KeyCode == Keys.C){

          if(agachado){
            levantar();            
           }else{
             agachar();
           }
       }

    }


     public void agachar(){
       this.agachado = true;

     //resto do codigo pra agachar
     }

     public void levantar(){
       this.agachado = false;

       //codigo pra levantar
    }
```

Comment: ok Amigo eu uso a unity versão 2017 ai alguns comandos não são reconhecidos ex: o KeyEventArgs

Comment: Desculpe, como a tag está de C# achei que a resposta poderia ajudar, mas o conceito é o mesmo, cria um sinalizador para indicar como o personagem está no momento, e ao apertar a tecla, verifica o sinalizador e direciona o comportamento, para abaixar ou levantar, e lembre-se de atualizar o sinalizador sempre que o personagem mudar, assim como no exemplo que está na resposta. Espero que ajude, um pouco xD